# while as a time linker or as a contrast linker?

Tags: meaning

Consider this quote:

> When these cells switch on, it triggers a loss of consciousness. After SWS, REM sleep begins. This mode is bizarre: a dreamer’s brain becomes highly active while the body’s muscles are paralysed, and breathing and heart rate become erratic. The purpose of REM sleep remains a biological mystery...

source: http://www.chemwatch.net/186247/what-happens-in-the-brain-during-sleep

In the sentence "a dreamer's brain becomes highly active while the body's muscles are paralyzed", do you think the word "while" indicates contrast here, or is it used a s time linker, meaning "when"?

Answer (score 1):

You cut off context of the sentence with excluding the "This mode is bizzare:" part. It means that during this mode/in this mode, a brain becomes highly active, and the body muscles are paralyzed.

A **Time linker**(when: during that mode, or its "right now"), *and a* ... **regular And.** The word while in context means these two things are happening in parallel - while in this mode, these [insert example things] are happening.

- While one thing happens, another does too.
- One thing happens and another does too.

From the stub context, it can mean time linker, regular and, and a contrast linker as well.

**EDIT:**
*It shouldn't be contrast linker, as contrast linkers usually have a comma before the while, which indicates an opposition to the first part of the compound sentence.*

Comment: REM sleep is also known as *paradoxical sleep* because the brain is highly active but the muscles are relaxed, a behaviour that may seem counterintuitive. Therefore, I'd say the "contrast linker" option is the most likely here.

Comment: Added clarification in the answer, and to add to my edit, i'd say that whoever reads the sentence should understand that it's not putting things in contrast, but rather, observing two types of happening in the specified mode.

Comment: I disagree with your conclusion. I think it's a contrast linker where the writer forgot to use a comma. The fact that they are pointing out a bizarre occurrence with REM sleep indicates that they're contrasting the two happenings specified. It doesn't make sense as a time linker in context.

Comment: In context, whether the writer forgot or not, is given.
I agree that if we do insert the comma, then it is definitely a contrast linker. However, the general feel of the overall context + text indicates that it's just two properties observed and stated, not put into contrast with each other. Hence, I'd say that the time linker is valid. "These two things happen while in bizarre REM mode."

Comment: I think you're missing something: everything after the colon is explaining _why_ REM sleep is "bizarre". That is, the contrast between the activity levels of the brain and muscles (which implicitly are usually correlated) is what makes REM sleep "bizarre".

Comment: I didn't miss that, nor did i choose to ignore it. My answer accounts for that. The mode is bizarre because of two/three properties. The contrast is inherent, but the usage of while itself is not a contrast linker, but a time linker. While in that mode, at the same time brain is highly active, muscles become paralyzed and heart rate erratic. The fact that you can detect the contrast is all great and dandy, but it isn't the purpose of the sentence itself. It's an observation versus a direct contrast.

Comment: The problem with that interpretation is that it intrinsically relies on the reader already knowing that the body's muscles being paralysed is part of REM sleep, because the sentence then becomes a simple statement of the brain being active at the same time as this is happening, and removes focus from the paralysis part.

Comment: "The problem with that interpretation is that it intrinsically relies on the reader already knowing" - No, it clearly does not require anything like that, or rely on that. The example sentence specifies it clearly, and absolutely. There is no contrast, just observations. The contrast is a consequence of the observed behaviors. What's being listed there are symptoms, not conflicting "powers that be".